# How can I get the network attribute for my Chef node?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have found ways to get a specific IP address:

```
node[:network][:interfaces][:eth1][:addresses].detect{|k,v| v[:family] == "inet" }.first
```

...but I need to find the "network" for the ip - ie 10.0.1.0/24

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd go for `node['network']['interfaces']['eth1']['routes'].select {|k,v| v['src'] == node['ipaddress'] }['destination']` (you may replace the node['ipaddress'] by your method in the question.

Comment: Might want to move this to an answer

Comment: Forgive me, but you lost me on the "you may replace the node['ipaddress'] by your method in question. I did get this working however: <%= "#{(node[:network][:interfaces][:eth1][:addresses].detect{|k,v| v[:family] == "inet" }.first).split(".")[0..-2].join(".")}.0/24" %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for `node['network']['interfaces']['eth1']['routes'].select {|k,v| v['src'] == node['ipaddress'] }['destination']` because under routes you'll have something like this:

```
  "routes": [
        {
          "destination": "default",
          "family": "inet",
          "via": "172.30.4.250"
        },
        {
          "destination": "172.30.4.0/22",
          "family": "inet",
          "scope": "link",
          "proto": "kernel",
          "src": "172.30.5.235"
        }
      ]
```

So destination with src being your ip is what you're looking for.

you may replace the `node['ipaddress']` by your method in the question something like this:

```
selected_ip = node[:network][:interfaces][:eth1][:addresses].detect{|k,v| v[:family] == "inet" }.first
node['network']['interfaces']['eth1']['routes'].select {|k,v| v['src'] == selected_ip }['destination']
```